# Is there a way to hide all divs inside of a parent div/container by adding an inline style to parent?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to hide all child divs inside of a parent container by adding an inline style to the parent div. I have tried both `visibility: hidden;` and `display: none;` Neither one seem to hide the child divs. I was thinking I could just use some jquery to loop through all child divs and add an inline style to each one, although I figure there must be a way that works.

Here is an example:

**`CSS`**

```
  .hero-content {
      text-align: center;
      height: 650px;
      padding: 80px 0 0 0;
    }

    .title, .description {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2
    }
```

**`HTML`**

```
<div class="hero-content">
   <div class="title"> This is a title </div>  
   <div class="description"> This is a description</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: "Neither one seem to hide to child divs" - you mean without also hiding the parent?

Comment: Wouaow .. all answers got upvoted. cool. Chrismass's comming.

Comment: I don't get your question, as adding `display: none` to a parent [will _always_ hide its child elements](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltxtt/2/) (that is not true, necessarily, of `visibility`--[it may hide them](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltxtt/3/), unless the child's `visibility` is [set otherwise](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltxtt/4/)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **cannot** hide *child* elements using an *inline style* on *parent* element, so use `display: none;` for your child elements, you don't need inline style for doing this

```
.hero-content > div.title,
.hero-content > div.description {
   display: none;
}
```

Or if you are going with jQuery solution, than add a `class` to the parent element and than use the below selector.

```
.hide_this > div.title,
.hide_this > div.description {
   display: none;
}
```

Now add `.hide_this` `class` on the parent element using jQuery.

```
$(".hero-content").addClass("hide_this");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H3ByE/) (Using [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/))

---

Or if you are a fan of `inline` style than here you go

```
$(".hero-content .title, .hero-content .description").css({"display":"none"});
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/H3ByE/1/)

Answer (score 6):

Using jquery ?

```
$(".hero-content > *").css('display','none');
```

It will add inlined style="display:none" to what ever is first level child ELEMENT of .hero-content.

This means :

```
<div class="hero-content">
   <div class="title"> This is a title </div>
   <div class="description"> This is a description</div>
    This text in NOT in an element so will remain visible.
</div>
```

Using css :

```
.hero-content > * {display:none}
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCgZK/)

[precisions about not in an element jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/aCgZK/1/)

Comment: Hey! Can i get a funny hat for answering on first winter day ?

Comment: This is bad.. `*` never use it unless required :)

Comment: Universal selector can badly used, true, but i't a universal selector, not the devil itself. Also, in this context it refers to 'all only first level childs' not everything on cssDom. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `z-index`, `display:none` is failing ....see this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltxtt/1/) with `z-index` removed and it works!!

**CSS**

```
.hero-content {
    text-align: center;
    height: 650px;
    padding: 80px 0 0 0;
}
.title, .description {
    position: relative;
    display:none
}
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer, because it shows that what the original question wants *can* be done, and it shows why the approach was not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use CSS selectors for this purpose.

`.hero-content div` will apply to all `div` elements inside an element with class `hero-content`.

`.hero-content > div` will apply to all `div` elements immediately inside an element with class `hero-content`.

So, your second CSS selector should be:

```
.hero-content div  {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CHeck this 1 :-

http://jsfiddle.net/8DGKB/

```
.hero-content div  {
    display: none;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Through the jQuery you have to used below code when loading your page.

```
<div Id="ParentDivId" class="hero-content">
   <div Id="ChildDivIdFirst" class="title"> This is a title </div>  
   <div Id="ChildDivIdSecond" class="description"> This is a description</div>  
</div>

  $("#ParentDivId").find('#ChildDivIdFirst').css('display','none')
  $("#ParentDivId").find('#ChildDivIdSecond').css('display','none')
```

Comment: Jeet, where do those selectors come from ? ( #ParentDivId and #ChildDivId)?

Comment: Please set your parent and child div id, then those id set in this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can affect all the children P tags like this, as well

```css
.hero_content {
  display: none;
}

.hero_content P {
  display: none;
}
```